# Native deployment of stellar pubnet

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

I was trying to setup stellar-core natively ( without docker) but couldn't find relevant docs on setting up databases, permissions ect.

Using docker, it's quite simple:

```
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/prashanr/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --pubnet
```

Native test-net can be setup using [stellar-quickstart](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md). But this sets up testnet. The doc only mentiones:

> Once installed you can easily modify either the stellar-core or
>   stellar-horizon configs to suit your needs or to connect to the SDF
>   Pubnet

But there is no proper documentation on how to setup dbs and what needs to be changed to use quickstart for pubnet. I found example public net config [here](https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/other/stellar-core-validator-example.cfg). But I guess only supplying config won't do much. DB also needs to be re-initialized.

I tried:

```
sudo -u stellar stellar-core --conf stellar-core.cfg new-db
```

which gives error:

```
019-09-18T10:51:13.450 GBXLV [default FATAL] Got an exception: Unable to create bucket directory: buckets [CommandLine.cpp:1015]
2019-09-18T10:51:13.450 GBXLV [default FATAL] Please report this bug along with this log file if this was not expected [CommandLine.cpp:1016]
```

Is there any proper documentation, article available on setting up stellar-core natively?